# Would accessing a same prototype variable 'x' through this.x create a separate copy?

Tags: javascript, html, prototype, this

I am trying to understand the difference between accessing a variable via `prototype` vs accessing the same through `this`. In one object, it seems to create a separate copy of `x` one for `this.x` and one for `*.prototype.x`. But in other, looks like both points to the same copy.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testing Promises</title>
</head>

<body>

<button type="button" onclick="test()"> Click Me</button>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    function Estimate() {
    }
    Estimate.prototype.sharedVar = 888;


    Estimate.prototype.print = function () {
        console.log("****************************************************");
        console.log("*      Shared Variable             :   ", this.sharedVar);
        console.log("*      Estimate Shared Variable    :   ", Estimate.prototype.sharedVar);
        console.log("****************************************************");
    }

    Estimate.prototype.update = function (value) {
        this.sharedVar = value + 100;
        Estimate.prototype.sharedVar = value + 300;
    }

    function test() {
        var o1 = new Estimate();
        var o2 = new Estimate();
        o1.print();
        o2.print();

        o1.update(555);

        o1.print();
        o2.print();

    }


</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Why does it print 655, 855 in `o1` whereas 855, 855 in `o2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a prototype property, it affects all of the objects with that prototype. When you use the keyword this, it affects only that instance.

The 2 statements in the function below are not equivalent. They are changing 2 separate variables. When you first initialized your objects, they had no properties, so the interpreter will search to see if the prototype has that property. When you called update, it added a new property to your instance. When you search for this.sharedVar the first time, that instance didn't have it so it will search prototype for shared var, and if it doesn't find it, it will keep going to Object's sharedVar.

In the before and after images you can see what is going on.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually `X.prototype.Y` is useful when you want to add same property (here `Y`) to every instance of `X` If you want a shared value between these element Then you can easily add a property to `X` itself or you can create a global variable which every thing has access to that value.

But if you want to make it completely hidden out of `X` objects scope then you can try this:

```js
var X = (function _X() {
  _X.SharedValue = 3;
  var myFunc = function() {
    _X.SharedValue++;
  };

  myFunc.prototype.getShared = () => _X.SharedValue;
  return myFunc;
}());

console.log(new X().getShared(), new X().getShared(), new X().getShared());
```